# Changing data of AsyncStorage Item REACT NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cart, asyncstorage

I'm building a cart in an Android app. I get stuck on deleting Items on the cart. My system is simple. When someone adds something on the cart: one object is stored first on the AsyncStorage. Then in my cart component, I getItem with AsyncStorage as well. This Item is called "cart".

In my cart views, I have the image, price and quantity of each item. Two buttons allow the user to modify the quantity of each item. But I'm getting stuck with deleting the item. I use slice to get the item to disappear but it just disappears from my cart component and the item still on the AsyncStorage so every time I refresh the cart component the Items that were deleted with slice reappear with the function GetItem.

So I'm trying to delete the object from AsyncStorage and from my cart component. 
This is my AssyncStorage Item cart:

```
onClickAddCart(data){

    const itemcart = {
      food: data,
      quantity:  1,
      price: data.price
    }

    AsyncStorage.getItem('cart').then((datacart)=>{
        if (datacart !== null) {
          // We have data!!
          const cart = JSON.parse(datacart)
          cart.push(itemcart)
          AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
        }
        else{
          const cart  = []
          cart.push(itemcart)
          AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
        }
        alert("Add Cart")
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
      })
  }
```

}

this is my get item

```
componentDidMount(){
AsyncStorage.getItem('cart').then((cart)=>{
  if (cart !== null) {
    const cartfood = JSON.parse(cart)
    this.setState({dataCart:cartfood})
  }
})
.catch((err)=>{
  alert(err)
})
```

}

this is my cart system

```
onChangeQuat(i, type){
        const cart = this.state.dataCart
        let cant = cart[i].quantity;

        if(type){
            cant = cant + 1
            cart[i].quantity = cant
            this.setState({
                dataCart:cart
            })
        }
        else if (type == false&&cant>=2){
            cant = cant -1
            cart[i].quantity = cant
            this.setState({
                dataCart:cart
            })
        }
        else if (type==false&&cant==1){
            AsyncStorage.setItem(cart, JSON.stringify({quantity: null }));
            cart.splice(i,1)
            this.setState({
                dataCart:cart
            })
        }
    }
```

The error I get is:
"you attempt to set the key '0' with the value..."quantity":1...on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of AsyncStorage.setItem() and AsyncStorage.mergeItem() to update cart with the cart items.

```
removeCartItem = async (index) => {
    try {
        const cart = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart');
        let cartItems = JSON.parse(cart);
        const updatedCartItems = cartItems.filter(function (e, itemIndex) { return itemIndex !== index });

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(updatedCartItems));
        await AsyncStorage.mergeItem('cart', JSON.stringify(updatedCartItems));

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error: ', error);
    }
};
```

Comment: I can't... I tried these but it just update in cart. The AsyncStorage still returning the first one

Comment: Are you trying to get the data just after setting it?

Comment: I'm trying to get the data to erase it...like when you click delete button in the cart it will delete from the cart.

Comment: Try adding await before each asyncstorage operation.